# opengl crashes when trying to apply textures

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to apply textures to opengl program, but the program just crashes for some reason, can someone tell me what I did wrong? Trying to fix this problem for two days now :/ works fine when color in fragment shader is set to some random color, but when color is:
vec4 textColor = texture(u_Texture, v_TextCoord);
color = textColor;

Edited:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#define alloca __builtin_alloca

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stb_image.h>

using namespace std;

static string ParseShader(const string& filepath);
static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const string& source);
static unsigned int CreateShader(const string& vertexShader, const string& fragmentShader);
void glCheckError();

    float vertex[] =
    {
    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,     // 0
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,     // 1
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,     // 2
   -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f      // 3
    };

    float vertexBack[] =
    {
    -0.6,  -0.6f, -0.5f,    // 0
    0.6f, -0.6f, -0.5f,     // 1
    0.6f,  0.6f, -0.5f,     // 2
    -0.6f, 0.6f, -0.5f      // 3
    };

    unsigned int indexes[] =
    {
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;


    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "GLFW failed to load!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    else
        cout << "GLFW loaded" << endl << endl;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        cout << "Error loading GLEW" << endl;
    else
        cout << "GLEW loaded - version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(ParseShader("shaders/vertex.shader"), ParseShader("shaders/fragment.shader"));
    glUseProgram(shader);


        // Make vertex position array
        unsigned int buffers;
        glGenBuffers(1, &buffers);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Make vertex position indexes out of arrays
        unsigned int ib;
        glGenBuffers(1, &ib);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indexes), indexes, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Position layout
        unsigned int posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, 0);

        // Texture layout
        unsigned int texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "texCoord");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
        glCheckError();
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));

        // Load image
        int h, w, v_bpp;
        unsigned char *image = stbi_load("texture.png", &w, &h, &v_bpp, 4);

        if(image == nullptr)
            cout << "failed to load image!" << endl;

        unsigned int texture_id;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        stbi_image_free(image);

        // Set slot
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_Texture");
        glUniform1i(location, 0);



        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window) && glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);


        glCheckError();
        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

static string ParseShader(const string& filepath) {
    ifstream stream(filepath);

    string line;
    stringstream code;

    while(getline(stream, line))
        code << line << "\n";

    return code.str();
}

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const string& source) {
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, NULL);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if(result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "Vertex" : "Fragment") << " shader!" << endl;
        cout << message << endl;

        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const string& vertexShader, const string& fragmentShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

void glCheckError() {
        GLenum err = glGetError();
        while(err!=GL_NO_ERROR) {
                string error;

                switch(err) {
                        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:      error="INVALID_OPERATION";      break;
                        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:           error="INVALID_ENUM";           break;
                        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:          error="INVALID_VALUE";          break;
                        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:          error="OUT_OF_MEMORY";          break;
                        case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:  error="INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION";  break;
                }

                cerr << err << " (" << error.c_str() << ")" <<endl;
                err=glGetError();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You totally screwed up your vertex attribute ponter setup:

> ```
>    // Position layout
>     unsigned int posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position");
>     glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
>     glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, 0);
> ```

First, you query for an attribute named `position`, but you never use that index, you instead use `0`.

> ```
>    // Texture layout
>     unsigned int texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "texCoord");
>     glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
>     glCheckError();
>     glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
> ```

Then, you query for `texCoord`, ignore it again, enable attribute array `1`, and *overwrite* the attribute pointer for attribute `0`.

THis means that attribute `1` has some undefined pointer value, and you have undefined behavior.

What most likely happens is that you are lucky when you not use the texture, because you only have one active attribute which happens to get location 0. And your GL implementation seems to ignore attribute arrays for non-active attributes, so it does not crash. When you have both attributes enables, chances are that they will be `0` and `1`, and there is no way not to dereference that invalid pointer.

Comment: forgot to change that back, was trying to see if that was the problem.
Originaly it looked like this:
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
Got that idea from this source code: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.2.textures_combined/textures_combined.cpp

Comment: You _still_ set the attribute pointer for attribute `0` twice. Actually, your code is n ow even worse than before, since you potentially have now _two_ invalid attribute pointers than just one.

Comment: Hows this:
<pre> <code>
        // Position layout  
        unsigned int posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position");  
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);  
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, 0);  

        // Texture layout  
        unsigned int texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "texCoord");  
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);  
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void*) (3 * sizeof(float)));

Comment: still not using the queried attribute indices

Comment: glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, 0); Do you mean this?
Mate give me an example if possible ^^

Comment: yes, I mean using the atual attribute indices as you queried them.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate ^^ Thanks for having patience with me, wish all the best dude :))

Comment: Not sure what the actual state of your code (and the issue) now is.